# detecting a cycle from a Graph

Tags: java, matrix, graph, cycle, depth-first-search

How to detect if a graph has a cycle or not from this part of code which shows the depth-first search an the graph is implemented in an adjacency matrix

```
   // ------------------------------------------------------------
    public void dfs() // depth-first search
    { // begin at vertex 0
        int k = 0;
        vertexList[0].wasVisited = true; // mark it
        displayVertex(0); // display it
        theStack.push(0); // push it
        while (!theStack.isEmpty()) // until stack empty,
        {
            // get an unvisited vertex adjacent to stack top
            int v = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(theStack.peek());
            int x = nAdjVisitedVertex(v);

            if (v == -1) // if no such vertex,
                theStack.pop();
            else // if it exists,
            {
                vertexList[v].wasVisited = true; // mark it
                displayVertex(v); // display it
                if (x == 2)
                    k++;

                theStack.push(v); // push it

            }
        } // end while
            // stack is empty, so we’re done
        for (int j = 0; j < nVerts; j++)
            // reset flags
            vertexList[j].wasVisited = false;

        if(k != 0)
            System.out.println("not a cycle");
        else
            System.out.println("cycle");

    } // end dfs
```

Comment: You seem to be struggling with asking good questions. We are a very helpful community, but you'll find us a lot more helpful if you ask a well thought-out question that shows you've put some effort into it. Please read through the FAQS for the site.

Comment: Is this a directed or undirected graph?

Comment: @workInAFishBowl Sorry, I searched in the net but I need this for today! I just need an idea to implement it myself not the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

While traversing the graph, you need to keep looking for already visited node. If you come across a node which is already visited, you have found a loop. If traversal finishes without getting any visited node, there is no loop in the graph. And regarding implementation, try first, if you face any problem, come back with the problem.

Comment: This only works for an undirected graph, but that's what Khan said he had

Comment: From the sample it seems like a undirected graph traversal. But what's sad is simple google search is coming up with so many running code, pseudo code, sample, example that it's overwhelming. So was it tried before asking for help??

Comment: I went back to your code before editing, in `getAdjUnvisitedVertex` you are returning a node iff it is not visited. And perhaps inside `nAdjVisitedVertex` you are checking if the node is visited or not. So all inputs to `nAdjVisitedVertex` has already been verified not visited. This makes the `if (x == 2)` never getting true. make `getAdjUnvisitedVertex` return all nodes sequentially, visited or not. And if you found any node visited, break out of everything, all loop, because you have found a loop, other wise you might get caught in the loop itself.  :)